# When sending a GET or POST request from the client to the server should appear dimming the screen and the message "Please wait .."

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, httprequest

Sorry for my english.

Development of the project: asp.net, c #.

The essence of the problem:
When sending a GET or POST request from the client to the server should appear dimming the screen and the message "Please wait ..". The message disappears after a request is made and the result is obtained.
Http request is not AJAX.

The search for solutions:

1. Works only with sending Ajax requests
   $('#element').ajaxSend().ajaxStop();
2. XMLHTTPRequest - Creates only new requests. Although I could be wrong.

   var xmlhttp = new XMLHTTPRequest();
   xmlhttp.open('GET', document.URL, true);
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     $('#element').show();
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             $('#element').hide();
            }
     }
   };
   xmlhttp.send(null);
3. Catch the form submission through jquery. Catch the click to link (tag ).

Help me, please:
Perhaps there is some function on javascript that can catch http request (not ajax request). Maybe there are other solutions to this problem..